# WP - проблема с url

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

Есть сайт на wp. При переходе на страницу категории в url появлялась подпись `category` - `site.ru/category/categoryName`. Изменил префикс для рубрик на `.`, теперь `category/` пропала из url.

Все было хорошо, выкатил сайт на препродакшен (сайт уже на сервере, но еще не доступен), контент менеджер и seo'шник начали над ним работать. Сегодня оказывается, что доступ к странице категории можно получить по любому url главное чтобы он заканчивался на slug страницы, тоесть на страницу `site.ru/categoryName` можно попасть через

- `site.ru/category/categoryName`
- `site.ru/blablabla/categoryName`
- `site.ru/123/321/432/52/categoryName`

Отключил все плагины для seo - не помогло. В чем причина даже не подозреваю. Спасибо за любой комментарий или наводку

**UPD**

Проблема найдена в настройке ссылок, была ошибка вместо `/%category%/%postname%/` было введено `/%category%/%postname%` - потерян `/` в конце

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема найдена в настройке ссылок, была ошибка вместо /%category%/%postname%/ было введено /%category%/%postname% - потерян / в конце

Answer (score 0):

Так быть не должно, и на чистом WP такого не происходит. Отключите все плагины, смените тему на стандартную - найдёте источник проблемы.

Чтобы удалить `/category/` из url, воспользуйтесь плагином [Remove Category URL](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/remove-category-url/).

Comment: Плагины отключал, тему менял, `Remove Category URL` тоже уже использую. Есть еще идеи?

Comment: Префикс на точку я не стал бы менять. Просто удалить надо префикс (сделать пустой строкой в админке). Других идей нет, явно где-то ваш код создаёт проблему. Попробуйте сами на голом WP - нет такой проблемы.

Comment: Да в том то и дело, что пробовал, у меня тот же сайт стоит на компьютере, только без сео и редирект плагинов и все работает как надо, а тут что-то накрутили без меня и не могу исправить

Comment: Я уже говорил - отключайте ВСЕ плагины по одному. После этого смените тему на стандартную. Перепишите все файлы ядра. На каком-то этапе увидите, что проблема исчезла.

Comment: Проблема найдена в настройке ссылок, была ошибка вместо `/%category%/%postname%/` было введено `/%category%/%postname%` - потерян `/` в конце. Можете просветить как это работало?

Comment: Так навскидку не скажу. Надо дебажить.